# Aurelia and Webpack, Common Chunks and SPA Config-Generate-Index-Html Setup

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia

I have a common chunks question. I am currently using https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin along with the common chunks but currently in my HTML without adding anything, app.css is loaded automatically. How can I prevent the autoloading of that resource? Also, my other bundle, about.css is also automatically being injected into the HTML. This happens before I even use an import or require statement.
I can restrict which chunks get loaded via

```
require('@easy-webpack/config-generate-index-html')
       ({minify: false, overrideOptions:{
        chunks: ['app',
              'aurelia-bootstrap',
              'aurelia',
              'common']
        }}),
```

My goal is to be able to load only the page specific styles and the page specific JS and then when the user navigates to another page, dynamically import the required resources.
Without adding anything, app.css is loaded automatically. How can I prevent the autoloading of that resource? Also, my other bundle, about.css is also automatically being injected into the HTML. This happens before I even use an import or require statement.
For example:

```
<link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="app.css rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I believe your question is answered here https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext-webpack. Read Resource and bundling configuration

Comment: @FabioLuz

Based on the resource loader, when I do npm run build, there are chunk files created. 
Why is the chunk file created as 0.chunk.js and not something like about.bundle.js?
How can I setup my index to load only the required chunk/bundle?
How can I have Webpack not automatically load in "app" by default which seems to just load in everything?
I can't find solid documentation on how to do this and stackoverflow hasn't thrown out any responses yet. Surely, most people that create a powerful SPA need to be able to do code splitting on their resources. Can we get some clarity?